# Construct a function

Tags: function, matlab, user-defined-functions, anonymous-function

starting from this code:

```
    clc, clear all, close all
tic

k1 = 0.01:0.1:100;
k2 = 0.01:0.1:100;
k3 = 0.01:0.1:100;

k = sqrt(k1.^2 + k2.^2 + k3.^2);

c = 1.476;
gamma = 3.9;

colors = {'cyan'};
Ek = (1.453*k.^4)./((1 + k.^2).^(17/6));
E = @(k) (1.453*k.^4)./((1 + k.^2).^(17/6));
E_int = zeros(1,numel(k1));
E_int(1) = 1.5;

for i = 2:numel(k)
    E_int(i) = E_int(i-1) - integral(E,k(i-1),k(i));
end

beta = c*gamma./(k.*sqrt(E_int));


F_11 = zeros(1,numel(k1));
F_22 = zeros(1,numel(k1));
F_33 = zeros(1,numel(k1));

count = 0;
for i = 1:numel(k1)
    count = count + 1;
    phi_11 = @(k2,k3) phi_11_new(k1,k2,k3,beta,i);
    phi_22 = @(k2,k3) phi_22_new(k1,k2,k3,beta,i);
    phi_33 = @(k2,k3) phi_33_new(k1,k2,k3,beta,i);
    F_11(count) = integral2(phi_11,-100,100,-100,100);
    F_22(count) = integral2(phi_22,-100,100,-100,100);
    F_33(count) = integral2(phi_33,-100,100,-100,100);
end

figure
hold on
plot(k1,F_11,'b')
plot(k1,F_22,'cyan')
plot(k1,F_33,'magenta')
hold off
```

where

```
function phi_11 = phi_11_new(k1,k2,k3,beta,i)
k = sqrt(k1(i).^2 + k2.^2 + k3.^2);
k30 = k3 + beta(i).*k1(i);
k0 = sqrt(k1(i).^2 + k2.^2 + k30.^2);
E_k0 = 1.453.*k0.^4./((1 + k0.^2).^(17/6));
C1 = (beta(i).*k1(i).^2).*(k1(i).^2 + k2.^2 - k3.*k30)./(k.^2.*(k1(i).^2 + k2.^2));
C2 = k2.*k0.^2./((k1(i).^2 + k2.^2).^(3/2)).*atan2((beta(i).*k1(i).*sqrt(k1(i).^2 + k2.^2)),(k0.^2 - k30.*k1(i).*beta(i)));
xhsi1 = C1 - k2./k1(i).*C2;
xhsi1_q = xhsi1.^2;
phi_11 = E_k0./(4.*pi.*k0.^4).*(k0.^2 - k1(i).^2 - 2.*k1(i).*k30.*xhsi1 + (k1(i).^2 + k2.^2).*xhsi1_q);
end

function phi_22 = phi_22_new(k1,k2,k3,beta,i)
k = sqrt(k1(i).^2 + k2.^2 + k3.^2);
k30 = k3 + beta(i).*k1(i);
k0 = sqrt(k1(i).^2 + k2.^2 + k30.^2);
E_k0 = 1.453.*k0.^4./((1 + k0.^2).^(17/6));
C1 = (beta(i).*k1(i).^2).*(k1(i).^2 + k2.^2 - k3.*k30)./(k.^2.*(k1(i).^2 + k2.^2));
C2 = k2.*k0.^2./((k1(i).^2 + k2.^2).^(3/2)).*atan2((beta(i).*k1(i).*sqrt(k1(i).^2 + k2.^2)),(k0.^2 - k30.*k1(i).*beta(i)));
xhsi2 = k2./k1(i).*C1 + C2;
xhsi2_q = xhsi2.^2;
phi_22 = E_k0./(4.*pi.*k0.^4).*(k0.^2 - k2.^2 - 2.*k2.*k30.*xhsi2 + (k1(i).^2 + k2.^2).*xhsi2_q);
end

function phi_33 = phi_33_new(k1,k2,k3,beta,i)
k = sqrt(k1(i).^2+k2.^2+k3.^2);
k30 = k3 + beta(i).*k1(i);
k0 = sqrt(k1(i).^2+k2.^2+k30.^2);
E_k0 = (1.453.*k0.^4./((1+k0.^2).^(17/6)));
phi_33 = (E_k0./(4*pi.*(k.^4))).*(k1(i).^2+k2.^2);
end
```

This procedure is leading me to results not matching some others coming from a study. The results I should match are posted below:

[image]

whereas mine look like these

[image]

It's quite easy to esteem how only the comp w match the theoretical results; therefore, I believe that the flaw may reside in the definition of beta outside the function phi_11_new (and phi_22_new).

May any of you suggest how to calculate beta within phi_11_new(and phi_22_new) instead than the way I currently do?

I thank you all in advance for supporting.

Best Regards,
fpe

Comment: Can you provide some sort of verification method for the results?

Comment: You mention that comp w matches the theoretical results, but in fact it does not. In the upper graph the value at point 1 is just over 0.1 and in the lower graph it is just under 0.1.

Comment: at least they are closer: that's what I meant, sorry. Hence, I do strongly believe that the mistake is in defining beta outside the phi_ii functions.

Comment: no ideas? I've still not been able to solve it

Comment: You say that you want to include the calculation of `beta` in the expression calculating the `phi`. But it is not clear how a new calculation of `beta` should look like. Should it use a combination of different values of `k1`, `k2` and `k3` in order to get an new value of `beta`? In the current calculation they are all identical vectors that are used element-wise. Could you provide a link to the work that you are trying to duplicate?

Comment: sure I can provide you with a link: http://rasei.colorado.edu/wind-research-internal1/Jakob_Mann.pdf.

Comment: at the moment beta stemms from k and E_int, gamma and c. I'd like to put the procedure calculating E_int and beta within the phi functions and then deleting k2 and k3 in the main code. I hope this will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have improved the interpolation so that it no longer breaks down for small values. It also returns more correct values since it now interpolates the logarithms of the values.

Here is the code, as it is now.

```
function test15()

[k1,k2,k3] = deal(0.01:0.1:400);

k = sqrt(k1.^2 + k2.^2 + k3.^2);

c = 1.476;
gamma = 3.9;

Ek = (1.453*k.^4)./((1 + k.^2).^(17/6));
E_int = 1.5-cumtrapz(k,Ek);
beta = c*gamma./(k.*sqrt(E_int));

[F_11,F_22,F_33] = deal(zeros(1,numel(k1)));

k_vec = k;
beta_vec = beta;

kLim = 100;

for ii = 1:numel(k1)
    phi_11 = @(k2,k3) phi_11_new(k1(ii),k2,k3,k_vec,beta_vec);
    phi_22 = @(k2,k3) phi_22_new(k1(ii),k2,k3,k_vec,beta_vec);
    phi_33 = @(k2,k3) phi_33_new(k1(ii),k2,k3,k_vec,beta_vec);
    F_11(ii) = quad2d(phi_11,-kLim,kLim,-kLim,kLim);
    F_22(ii) = quad2d(phi_22,-kLim,kLim,-kLim,kLim);
    F_33(ii) = quad2d(phi_33,-kLim,kLim,-kLim,kLim);
end

figure
loglog(k1,F_11,'b')
hold on
loglog(k1,F_22,'cyan')
loglog(k1,F_33,'magenta')
hold off
grid on

end

function phi_11 = phi_11_new(k1,k2,k3,k_vec,beta_vec)
k = sqrt(k1^2 + k2.^2 + k3.^2);

log_beta_vec = interp1(log(k_vec),log(beta_vec),log(k(:)),'linear','extrap');
log_beta = reshape(log_beta_vec,size(k));
beta = exp(log_beta);

k30 = k3 + beta*k1;
k0 = sqrt(k1^2 + k2.^2 + k30.^2);
E_k0 = 1.453*k0.^4./((1 + k0.^2).^(17/6));
C1 = (beta*k1^2).*(k1^2 + k2.^2 - k3.*k30)./(k.^2.*(k1^2 + k2.^2));
C2 = k2.*k0.^2./((k1^2 + k2.^2).^(3/2)).*atan2((beta*k1.*sqrt(k1^2 + k2.^2)),(k0.^2 - k30*k1.*beta));
xhsi1 = C1 - (k2/k1).*C2;
xhsi1_q = xhsi1.^2;
phi_11 = E_k0./(4.*pi.*k0.^4).*(k0.^2 - k1^2 - 2*k1*k30.*xhsi1 + (k1^2 + k2.^2).*xhsi1_q);
end

function phi_22 = phi_22_new(k1,k2,k3,k_vec,beta_vec)
k = sqrt(k1^2 + k2.^2 + k3.^2);

log_beta_vec = interp1(log(k_vec),log(beta_vec),log(k(:)),'linear','extrap');
log_beta = reshape(log_beta_vec,size(k));
beta = exp(log_beta);

k30 = k3 + beta*k1;
k0 = sqrt(k1^2 + k2.^2 + k30.^2);
E_k0 = 1.453*k0.^4./((1 + k0.^2).^(17/6));
C1 = (beta*k1^2).*(k1^2 + k2.^2 - k3.*k30)./(k.^2.*(k1^2 + k2.^2));
C2 = k2.*k0.^2./((k1^2 + k2.^2).^(3/2)).*atan2((beta*k1.*sqrt(k1^2 + k2.^2)),(k0.^2 - k30.*k1.*beta));
xhsi2 = (k2/k1).*C1 + C2;
xhsi2_q = xhsi2.^2;
phi_22 = E_k0./(4.*pi.*k0.^4).*(k0.^2 - k2.^2 - 2.*k2.*k30.*xhsi2 + (k1^2 + k2.^2).*xhsi2_q);
end

function phi_33 = phi_33_new(k1,k2,k3,k_vec,beta_vec)
k = sqrt(k1^2+k2.^2+k3.^2);

log_beta_vec = interp1(log(k_vec),log(beta_vec),log(k(:)),'linear','extrap');
log_beta = reshape(log_beta_vec,size(k));
beta = exp(log_beta);

k30 = k3 + beta*k1;
k0 = sqrt(k1^2+k2.^2+k30.^2);
E_k0 = (1.453*k0.^4./((1+k0.^2).^(17/6)));
phi_33 = (E_k0./(4*pi*(k.^4))).*(k1^2+k2.^2);
end
```

The figure seems to agree with the original result quite well. Even if there still are some differences.

Side note: Since a k-value of 100 is set as an upper limit in the simulation the values greater than this in the figure are incorrect. They are calculated without using all values in the full (k2,k3)-"circle". We can also see a deviation for these values.

[image: New loglog-plot of F11, F_22 and F_33.]

Comment: btw, just for sake of correctness, if gamma is reduced to zero, the logarithm within interp1 fails since beta is zero-valued. Luckily I don't operate with zero valued gamma, but I was only trying to extensively test the code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is what I have got at the moment. I would like to hear what you think about it - it is not perfect yet. I have not access to the functions `integral` or `integral2` so if you can reinsert them (instead of my `quad2d` for example) and test the code you might get better results than I have now.

My first thought was to calculate `beta` in a for-loop for every triplet of `[k1,k2,k3]` in the `phi`-functions. This turned out to be extremely slow so I have instead used a vector of `k`-values and calculated the corresponding vector `beta` just as you did before. These two vectors are then passed to `phi` where the values are used in an interpolation function (`interp1`) to find the `beta`-values of specific `k`-values.

```
function myFunction()

[k1,k2,k3] = deal(0.01:0.1:400);

k = sqrt(k1.^2 + k2.^2 + k3.^2);

c = 1.476;
gamma = 3.9;

Ek = (1.453*k.^4)./((1 + k.^2).^(17/6));
E_int = 1.5-cumtrapz(k,Ek);
beta = c*gamma./(k.*sqrt(E_int));

[F_11,F_22,F_33] = deal(zeros(1,numel(k1)));

k_vec = k;
beta_vec = beta;

for ii = 1:numel(k1)
    phi_11 = @(k2,k3) phi_11_new(k1(ii),k2,k3,k_vec,beta_vec);
    phi_22 = @(k2,k3) phi_22_new(k1(ii),k2,k3,k_vec,beta_vec);
    phi_33 = @(k2,k3) phi_33_new(k1(ii),k2,k3,k_vec,beta_vec);
    F_11(ii) = quad2d(phi_11,-100,100,-100,100);
    F_22(ii) = quad2d(phi_22,-100,100,-100,100);
    F_33(ii) = quad2d(phi_33,-100,100,-100,100);
end

figure
loglog(k1,F_11,'b')
hold on
loglog(k1,F_22,'cyan')
loglog(k1,F_33,'magenta')
hold off
grid on

end

function phi_11 = phi_11_new(k1,k2,k3,k_vec,beta_vec)
k = sqrt(k1^2 + k2.^2 + k3.^2);

beta = reshape(interp1(k_vec,beta_vec,k(:)),size(k));

k30 = k3 + beta*k1;
k0 = sqrt(k1^2 + k2.^2 + k30.^2);
E_k0 = 1.453*k0.^4./((1 + k0.^2).^(17/6));
C1 = (beta*k1^2).*(k1^2 + k2.^2 - k3.*k30)./(k.^2.*(k1^2 + k2.^2));
C2 = k2.*k0.^2./((k1^2 + k2.^2).^(3/2)).*atan2((beta*k1.*sqrt(k1^2 + k2.^2)),(k0.^2 - k30*k1.*beta));
xhsi1 = C1 - (k2/k1).*C2;
xhsi1_q = xhsi1.^2;
phi_11 = E_k0./(4.*pi.*k0.^4).*(k0.^2 - k1^2 - 2*k1*k30.*xhsi1 + (k1^2 + k2.^2).*xhsi1_q);
end

function phi_22 = phi_22_new(k1,k2,k3,k_vec,beta_vec)
k = sqrt(k1^2 + k2.^2 + k3.^2);

beta = reshape(interp1(k_vec,beta_vec,k(:)),size(k));

k30 = k3 + beta*k1;
k0 = sqrt(k1^2 + k2.^2 + k30.^2);
E_k0 = 1.453*k0.^4./((1 + k0.^2).^(17/6));
C1 = (beta*k1^2).*(k1^2 + k2.^2 - k3.*k30)./(k.^2.*(k1^2 + k2.^2));
C2 = k2.*k0.^2./((k1^2 + k2.^2).^(3/2)).*atan2((beta*k1.*sqrt(k1^2 + k2.^2)),(k0.^2 - k30.*k1.*beta));
xhsi2 = (k2/k1).*C1 + C2;
xhsi2_q = xhsi2.^2;
phi_22 = E_k0./(4.*pi.*k0.^4).*(k0.^2 - k2.^2 - 2.*k2.*k30.*xhsi2 + (k1^2 + k2.^2).*xhsi2_q);
end

function phi_33 = phi_33_new(k1,k2,k3,k_vec,beta_vec)
k = sqrt(k1^2+k2.^2+k3.^2);

beta = reshape(interp1(k_vec,beta_vec,k(:)),size(k));

k30 = k3 + beta*k1;
k0 = sqrt(k1^2+k2.^2+k30.^2);
E_k0 = (1.453*k0.^4./((1+k0.^2).^(17/6)));
phi_33 = (E_k0./(4*pi*(k.^4))).*(k1^2+k2.^2);
end
```

This produces the following figure. Note that the integration does not succeed for the smallest values of `k1`.

[image: F_11, F_22 and F_33 in a loglog-plot.]

**Edit - A comment on calculating beta within the phi-functions**

Since you essentially tried the same thing that I did initially, I have added an example of how I calculated the `beta` matrix within the `phi`-functions. Note that this code is so slow that I have never actually run it to completion.

```
function phi_11 = phi_11_new(k1,k2,k3)
k = sqrt(k1^2 + k2.^2 + k3.^2);

c = 1.476;
gamma = 3.9;
beta = zeros(size(k));
E = @(x) (1.453*x.^4)./((1 + x.^2).^(17/6));
for ii = 1:size(k,1)
    for jj = 1:size(k,2)
        E_int = 1.5-quad(E,0.001,k(ii,jj));
        beta(ii,jj) = c*gamma/(k(ii,jj)*sqrt(E_int));
    end
end


k30 = k3 + beta*k1;
k0 = sqrt(k1^2 + k2.^2 + k30.^2);
E_k0 = 1.453*k0.^4./((1 + k0.^2).^(17/6));
C1 = (beta*k1^2).*(k1^2 + k2.^2 - k3.*k30)./(k.^2.*(k1^2 + k2.^2));
C2 = k2.*k0.^2./((k1^2 + k2.^2).^(3/2)).*atan2((beta*k1.*sqrt(k1^2 + k2.^2)),(k0.^2 - k30*k1.*beta));
xhsi1 = C1 - (k2/k1).*C2;
xhsi1_q = xhsi1.^2;
phi_11 = E_k0./(4.*pi.*k0.^4).*(k0.^2 - k1^2 - 2*k1*k30.*xhsi1 + (k1^2 + k2.^2).*xhsi1_q);
end
```

Comment: I will check it as soon as I can. btw I coded another possible solution. I will post it, and I'd like knowing your opinion

Answer (score 0):

currently I'm running a different version of the above code.

It follows as

```
clc, clear all, close all
tic



k1 = (0.01:0.1:100);

c = 1.476;
gamma = 3.9;


F_11 = zeros(1,numel(k1));
F_22 = zeros(1,numel(k1));
F_33 = zeros(1,numel(k1));

count = 0;
for i = 1:numel(k1)
    count = count + 1;
    phi_11 = @(k2,k3) phi_11_new(k1,k2,k3,gamma,i);
    phi_22 = @(k2,k3) phi_22_new(k1,k2,k3,gamma,i);
    phi_33 = @(k2,k3) phi_33_new(k1,k2,k3,gamma,i);
    F_11(count) = integral2(phi_11,-100,100,-100,100);
    F_22(count) = integral2(phi_22,-100,100,-100,100);
    F_33(count) = integral2(phi_33,-100,100,-100,100);
end
```

This time phi_11, phi_22 and phi_33 are given as

```
function phi_11 = phi_11_new(k1,k2,k3,gamma,i)
k = sqrt(k1(i).^2 + k2.^2 + k3.^2);
beta = gamma./((k.^(2/3)).*sqrt(hypergeom([1/3,17/6],4/3,-k.^(-2))));  
k30 = k3 + beta.*k1(i);
k0 = sqrt(k1(i).^2 + k2.^2 + k30.^2);
E_k0 = 1.453.*k0.^4./((1 + k0.^2).^(17/6));
C1 = (beta(i).*k1(i).^2).*(k0.^2 - 2.*k30.^2 + beta.*k30.*k1(i))./(k.^2.*(k1(i).^2 + k2.^2));
C2 = k2.*k0.^2./((k1(i).^2 + k2.^2).^(3/2)).*atan2((beta.*k1(i).*sqrt(k1(i).^2 + k2.^2)),(k0.^2 - k30.*k1(i).*beta));
xhsi1 = C1 - k2./k1(i).*C2;
xhsi1_q = xhsi1.^2;
phi_11 = E_k0./(4.*pi.*k0.^4).*(k0.^2 - k1(i).^2 - 2.*k1(i).*k30.*xhsi1 + (k1(i).^2 + k2.^2).*xhsi1_q);
end

function phi_22 = phi_22_new(k1,k2,k3,gamma,i)
k = sqrt(k1(i).^2 + k2.^2 + k3.^2);
beta = gamma./((k.^(2/3)).*sqrt(hypergeom([1/3,17/6],4/3,-k.^(-2)))); 
k30 = k3 + beta.*k1(i);
k0 = sqrt(k1(i).^2 + k2.^2 + k30.^2);
E_k0 = 1.453.*k0.^4./((1 + k0.^2).^(17/6));
C1 = (beta.*k1(i).^2).*(k0.^2 - 2.*k30.^2 + beta.*k1(i).*k30)./(k.^2.*(k1(i).^2 + k2.^2));
C2 = k2.*k0.^2./((k1(i).^2 + k2.^2).^(3/2)).*atan2((beta.*k1(i).*sqrt(k1(i).^2 + k2.^2)),(k0.^2 - k30.*k1(i).*beta));
xhsi2 = (k2./k1(i)).*C1 + C2;
xhsi2_q = xhsi2.^2;
phi_22 = E_k0./(4.*pi.*k0.^4).*(k0.^2 - k2.^2 - 2.*k2.*k30.*xhsi2 + (k1(i).^2 + k2.^2).*xhsi2_q);
end

function phi_33 = phi_33_new(k1,k2,k3,gamma,i)
k = sqrt(k1(i).^2+k2.^2+k3.^2);
beta = gamma./((k.^(2/3)).*sqrt(hypergeom([1/3,17/6],4/3,-k.^(-2)))); 
k30 = k3 + beta.*k1(i);
k0 = sqrt(k1(i).^2+k2.^2+k30.^2);
E_k0 = (1.453.*k0.^4./((1+k0.^2).^(17/6)));
phi_33 = (E_k0./(4*pi.*(k.^4))).*(k1(i).^2+k2.^2);
end
```

Please notice that now beta is calculated within the phi functions. Furthermore, I'm using an equivalent expression of beta. For more details, check the picture below out

[image]

Hence, in the updated model, I'm calling hypergeom which is rather slow performing.
That's the main reason why I'd like to calculate beta as in the first code, by means of the energy spectrum integral.

Btw, at the moment I have no idea how to perfrom this successfully.

Best regards,
fpe

Comment: Yes, there seems to be a problem in your current calculation of the energy spectrum. I will look into it some more. But it seems like it should be possible to calculate outside your function for `phi`.

Comment: I just have the feeling that the energy spectrum calculated from the outside is jeopardizing the procedure yielding to F_11, F_22 and F_33. Cause when I call integral2 k2 and k3 are not those as given at the beginning. I thank you a lot for your support.